# How to write a windows batch script that can run a process everyday

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have a Python process that must be run at 00:30 AM (local time) every day. How can I write such Windows script that can run my Python program.

Comment: I don't see the problem with using task scheduler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SCHTASKS /Create /S ABC /U user /P password /RU runasuser /RP runaspassword /SC DAILY /ST 03:00 /TN report /TR notepad.exe
```

Is one of many examples from `Schtasks /create /? (although I changed it to 3am daily)`.

If using redirection start the program

```
cmd /c <rest of command line>
```